# GWT Native Method Warning

Tags: javascript, gwt, native

I'm doing a project in GWT to deploy in AppEngine and I'm getting a warning in Eclipse saying:
JavaScript parsing: Expected an identifier in JSNI 
 reference
Any ideas on what's causing this?

```
public void callFacebookAPI(String url) {
        JsonpRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
        requestBuilder.requestObject(url, new AsyncCallback<FbUser>() {

            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                System.out.println("FAIL" );
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FbUser result) {
                facebookUser = result;
                System.out.println("Facebook name:" + facebookUser.getName());
            }

        });     
    }


    private final native void doFbLoginFunction() /*-{


    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            //return response.session;
            var accessToken = response.accessToken;
            var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=";

            var facebookUrl = url + accessToken;
            @com.google.gwt.smartpark.client.map.SmartPark::callFacebookAPI(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/
String;)(facebookUrl);         

        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callFacebookAPI` is not static so there must be something before the `@` in the reference in JSNI, e.g.

```
var that = this;
$wnd.FB.login($entry(function(response) {
   // ...
   that.@com.google.gwt.smartpark.client.map.SmartPack::callFacebookAPI(Ljava/lang/String;)(facebookUrl);
   // ...
}));
```

Also, your `callFacebookAPI` takes a single argument, so the JSNI signature should have a single `Ljava/lang/String;`.

Comment: Something like this? 
 
 var that = this;
$wnd.FB.login($entry(function(response) {
    
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            //return response.session;
            var accessToken = response.accessToken;
            var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=";
            
            var facebookUrl = url + accessToken;
            that.@com.google.gwt.smartpark.client.map.SmartPark::callFacebookAPI(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/
String;)(facebookUrl);         
            
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });


 
 }-*/;

Comment: Ah, why are you having `java/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;` when your method takes a single argument?